# How can I click on button in a column that contains an element td style? In Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, web, robotframework, built-in, browser-automation

Im making robotframework automation tests cases

I need to click on button which is in the same line another element. I need to verify the color of the element and click on button. I need to verify it cuz the validation after clicking on button depends on the type of the option I clicked. There are two options, the option which blue and red color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z1AF.png)

Comment: Can you provide some info on what you have already tried and what would be the part that is causing issues with those? Please try to provide some reproducible example of your issue. Also you can add descriptions to your images and links so we know what we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a custom keyword(s) in Python, that will

```
${list_of_rows_buttons_to_click}=    Get Buttons To Click
```

1. get table data AND styles
2. possibly de-serialize previous
3. go trough rows
4. if style "red color" detected in column 2 add row id to return list of row_id:s

   Press buttons in Rows   ${list_of_rows_buttons_to_click}

Python libraries you most likely need (did de-serializing in `numpy` myself):

```
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree, html
from robot.api import logger
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
```

`lmxl`, `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` are needed, if you an not get table data easily to Robot Framework - or if you want a bit more graceful solution.